# w32tm does not exist as an installed service

Tags: windows-10

I've been having trouble with the time on my Windows 10 PC.  I've googled several different solutions.  The first one I tried said to do a

```
w32tm /unregister
w32tm /register
```

When I did the second command, it said something like "Service has been marked for deletion".

Now if I do anything involving w32tm or W32Time, I get some variant of "The specified service does not exist as an installed service".

How do I re-install the time service without re-installing Windows?

Comment: Do you have an application running that locks the Service Manager? Stuff like Process Explorer.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting then running those commands again?

Comment: Daniel B - I am not running any thing that locks the service manager that I know of (definitely not Process Explorer).  I did install CrashPlan about a month ago.

Comment: Twisty - I tried running commands again, but I have not tried rebooting.  I'll do that as soon as I finish what I'm doing. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Twisty - that seems to have done it. I rebooted, re-ran the "w3tm  /register" command, and did a "net start w32time".  It seems to be running again. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this service is not found in "Turn Windows features on & off" or any other place. But the command you gave:

```
w32tm /register
```

Is the actual way to install it (using a command prompt which was *Run as Administrator*). Sometimes you need a reboot to put things in order, but I actually just waited a while without rebooting. Here is my sequence of commands showing that it works:

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>w32tm /config /update
The following error occurred: The specified service does not exist as an installed service. (0x80070424)

(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>w32tm /register
W32Time successfully registered.

(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>w32tm /query /source
The following error occurred: The service has not been started. (0x80070426)

(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>net start w32time
The Windows Time service is starting.
The Windows Time service was started successfully.

(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>w32tm /query /source
Local CMOS Clock
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow commands to start w32time and resync windows time: *Must be run as administrator*

```
w32tm /unregister
w32tm /register
net start w32time
w32tm /resync
```

Comment: You can use this batch script for resync the Windows time every start up.

Comment: The OP clearly stated that they tried the unregister/register commands already and were receiving errors when they did so. The answer already given covers this.

Comment: /resync is not described in the "Tomasz Gandor" answer, which is the only other answer at this point.

Answer (score 0):

it is quite likely you have made the same mistake as I did.
net start w32tm
This will always return this error message because the service name is not the same as the command line utility name.

The service name is w32time.
net start w32time

Good old Microsoft, I swear they do it deliberately.